# how save parameters in domain wih redirect on htaccess?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, web, redirect

i have problem with redirects in my domain

when i go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) - my doman redirect me to example.com - its ok! but,

when i go to [www.example.com/test](http://www.example.com/test) - my domain redirect me to example.com without /test...
why?
somebody help me?

code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where is your htaccess located?

Comment: public_html>example.com>here

Comment: Is `test` a directory ?

Comment: yes, test is a directory, BUT when i go to /test/index.php redirect works.

Comment: # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
is test a directory in the project so you enter ` /test` redirect to `/` because `test/index.php` not directory but `test` is a directory

Comment: ok, so what can i do?